# ¿Como utilizar los botones para almacenar información en PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, php7, symfony

buenas tardes, tengo la siguiente duda con el manejo de botones en php, tengo un formulario sencillo, el cuál esta compuesto de la siguiente manera, un input y dos botones, la funcionalidad del formulario es la siguiente:

El primer botón tiene de nombre "Agrega Datos", dentro de su código esta compuesto con un if que detecta la pulsasión del botón, al detectar dicho clic se agrega el string que se encuentra en el campo de texto, este string se almacena en un array.

El segundo botón de nombre "Mostrar Datos", lo que debería hacer es mostrar el contenido de dicho array.

Me he percatado que cuando pulso el botón nombrado "Mostrar Datos" este no toma el valor que almacena el array, me muestra un array con información vacía.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar el inconveniente con el segundo botón?, ¿Me pueden indicar que información debo investigar para hacer la respectiva búsqueda?.

De antemano muchas gracias, comparto el código a continuación.

```
<?php
    
    $cajonValores=[];
    $insertaDato='';
    
    if(isset($_REQUEST['txtEnviarDatos'])){
        $insertaDato=$_REQUEST['txtArray'];
        array_push($cajonValores,$insertaDato);
        print_r($cajonValores);
    }
    
    if(isset($_REQUEST['txtMostrarDatos'])){
        print_r($cajonValores);
    }
    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo 'Ordenar array'; ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
            <label>Ingresa Datos</label><input type="text" name="txtArray" placeholder="Ingresa datos de tu array" /><br/></br/>
            <input type="submit" name="txtEnviarDatos" value="Agrega Datos" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="txtMostrarDatos" value="Muesetra Datos" /><br/><br/>
        </form>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que hace un `input` de tipo `submit` es enviar la información del formulario y recargar la pagina. Intenta hacerlo sin el uso del formulario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por cada `submit` estas mandando el formulario a través del método POST. Así se ve usando tu boton agregar datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este hace una petición mandando esos datos al servidor y asignando `txtArray` y `TxtEnviarDatos` a las variables $_REQUEST. El problema con esas variables es que están siendo sobrescritas con tu próxima petición y el valor almacenado en `$cajonValores` también se pierde por que lo estas reiniciando en cada petición con:

```
 $cajonValores=[];
```

Además de que para que puedas recuperar el valor en tu próxima petición necesitarías guardarlo en una BD, Cookies o como una variable de session.

En el caso de  [sesiones](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-start.php) te quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
    session_start();// se inicia la session
    //se comprueba si ya existe una variable de session con el nombre cajonValores
    if(isset($_SESSION['cajonValores'])){
        //si ya existe se le asigna a la var cajonValores
        $cajonValores = $_SESSION['cajonValores'];
    } else {
        //si no existe se crea el arreglo
        $cajonValores=[];
    }
    
    $insertaDato='';
    
    if(isset($_REQUEST['txtEnviarDatos']) {
        $insertaDato=$_REQUEST['txtArray'];
        array_push($cajonValores, $insertaDato);
        //se guarda en la session el valor de cajon valores
        $_SESSION['cajonValores'] = $cajonValores;

    }
    
    if(isset($_REQUEST['txtMostrarDatos'])){
        if(isset($_SESSION['cajonValores'])){
            print_r($_SESSION['cajonValores']);
        } else {
            echo 'No hay ningun dato';
        }
       
    }
    // Para eliminar las variables de session se usa unset, por lo que podrias crear un boton para ello
    // unset($_SESSION['cajonValores']);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias por el apoyo brindado, he modificado un poco el código, agregue más campos de texto y utilice el modelo que me brindaste para poder generar uno propio, bueno, solamente hice una pequeña modificación.

Muchísimas gracias por la aportación, espero algún día poder regresar el favor.

```
<?php

session_start();

$cajonValores=[];
$texto1='';
$texto2='';
$texto3='';
$unir='';
$muestraDatos='';
$msmEnvioDato='';

if(!isset($_SESSION['miSesion'])){
    $cajonValores=[];
}else{
    if(isset($_SESSION['miSesion'])){
        $cajonValores=$_SESSION['miSesion'];
    }
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['btnAgregaDato'])){
    $texto1=$_REQUEST['txtTexto1'];
    $texto2=$_REQUEST['txtTexto2'];
    $texto3=$_REQUEST['txtTexto3'];
    $unir=($texto1.'<br/>'.$texto2.'<br/>'.$texto3);
    array_push($cajonValores,$unir);
    $_SESSION['miSesion']=$cajonValores;
    $msmEnvioDato.='Los datos estan almacenados correctamente';
}

if(isset($_SESSION['miSesion']) && isset($_REQUEST['btnMuestraDato'])){
    $muestraDatos=$_SESSION['miSesion'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['miSesion']) && isset($_REQUEST['btnCierraSesion'])){
    unset($_SESSION['miSesion']);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title><?php echo 'Sesiones en PHP'; ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    <section>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="POST">
            <label>Texto 1</label><input type="text" name="txtTexto1" placeholder="Ingresa el primer texto" /><br/><br/>
            <label>Texto 2</label><input type="text" name="txtTexto2" placeholder="Ingresa el segundo texto" /><br/><br/>
            <label>Texto 3</label><input type="text" name="txtTexto3" placeholder="Ingresa el tercer texto" /><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="btnAgregaDato" value="Agrega Dato" /><br><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="btnMuestraDato" value="Muestra Dato" /><br><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="btnCierraSesion" value="Cierra Sesion" /><br><br/>
        </form>
    </section>

<div>
    <?php if($muestraDatos): ?>
        <?php 

            foreach($muestraDatos as $valorDato){
                echo $valorDato.'<br/>';
            }

        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div>
    <?php if($msmEnvioDato): ?>
        <?php echo $msmEnvioDato; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```